# Layout CSS different result IE, Firefox and Chrome

Tags: css, overflow, css-tables, tablerow

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                border:0;
                overflow:hidden;
                padding:0;
                margin:0;
            }

            .tablecontent {
                display: table; 
                height:100%; 
                width:100%;
            }

            .head {
                display: table-row; 
                height:10%; 
                background-color:red;
            }

            .content {
                display: table-row; 
                height:85%; 
                background-color:black; 
            }

            .bodycontent {
                padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
            }

            .foot {
                display: table-row;
                height:5%;
                background-color:yellow;
            }

            .contentscroll {
                height:100%;
                background-color:blue;
                overflow-y:scroll
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="tablecontent">
            <div class="head">HEADER</div>

            <div class="bodycontent content">
                <div class="tablecontent">
                    <div class="head">INNER-HEADER</div>
                    <div class="content">

                        <div class="contentscroll"></div>

                    </div>  
                    <div class="foot">INNER-FOOTER</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="foot">FOOTER</div>
    </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

This shows different results in IE6, Firefox and Chrome (sorry, I can't post images). You must add load in div (`overflow-y:scroll`) to force the overflow.
Repeat, for example:

```
alskdjflasjdfklasjdflajk<br/>
alskdjflasjdfklasjdflajk<br/>
alskdjflasjdfklasjdflajk<br/>
```

IE6 - OK padding and overflow
Chrome - OK overflow. padding?
Firefox - overflow and padding?

Comment: Do you use **CSS reset**?

Comment: Welcome to the world of web development.

Comment: for example:
    * {
        border:0;
        overflow:hidden; 
        padding:0; 
        margin:0;
    }
    No work

Comment: I've been in this world 10 years. I had never seen differences between FF and Chrome

Comment: Well, there are a lot.

Comment: Which versions of browsers are you using? (And: http://ie6isolderthanyourgrandpa.com/)

Comment: I already know that IE does not but... Chrome and FF do not meet the standard?

Comment: IE6, FF v19.0.2 and Chrome 26.0.1410.43

Comment: use a doctype. you'll get inconsistent results between browsers if you don't specify one, especially *especially* IE.

Comment: When I add the doctype does not work in any of the browsers. That's progress, thanks.

Comment: what do you mean 'does not work'? does the page display, does your css give you unexpected results, what? if your page is a mess after adding a doctype I'd suggest it is a syntax error, you can read up on correct syntax here: http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html

Comment: Sorry, me code no work.

Comment: @TTo314 sorry but I don't know what you're actually asking here, and aside from telling us that it "doesn't work" we don't know what isn't working right. without atleast telling us what the expected outcome is, we can't help you fix it - you won't get a good answer unless you can explain what your problem actually is. p.s, here's a fiddle of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/yKkVj/ can you tell me what isn't working right based on that?

Comment: @jammypeach forgive my lack of practice on this website. I use this website only for consultation. The desired result is this http://flic.kr/p/eaKbDN. Soon will update the jsfiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yKkVj/7/ 
Here is the code. In Chrome, you will see that the padding does not work but if overflow. In firefox does not work either.
In IE6, jsfiddle does not work well.

Comment: Another solution but does not work in IE. http://jsfiddle.net/mEa4Z/

Comment: In this example: jsfiddle.net/yKkVj/7 if you have `display: table-row` and `padding: 10px` for the same tag (`<div class="bodycontent content">`) then the padding will be ignored.

Comment: Ok, @Barnee http://jsfiddle.net/yKkVj/10/. In Chrome, the solution would be valid unless they escape some pixels to the right. The padding is solved. Thanks.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yKkVj/11/ Perfect padding, except IE

Answer (score 0):

Add `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` before `<html>`, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
```

give to:

```
.bodycontent {
    display: block;
}
.contentscroll {
    min-height: 50px; /* for example */
}
```

Comment: Well, padding works on any browser. In Chrome, overflow works but layout only has X px. FF and IE do not work overflow.